# How do i stop crystal report from requesting parameters at runtime even after i supply them from c# code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I already provided the parameters from the code behind as shown below, but each time i run, crystal report still requests parameters. Is there a block of code i am missing?

```
    string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SCHOOLConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlDataAdapter DA;
    SqlDataAdapter dataAdap;
    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    ReportDocument RD = new ReportDocument();
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    myConnection.Open();
    DA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Exams WHERE AdmissionNo='RLA 0034'", myConnection);
    DA.Fill(DS);
    dataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM RESULT WHERE AdmissionNo='RLAS  0005'", myConnection);
    dataAdap.Fill(dataSet);
    RD.Load(Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReport1.rpt"));
    RD.SetParameterValue("PicPath",@"C:\Users\Me\Pictures\abu.jpg");
    RD.DataSourceConnections.Clear();
    RD.SetDataSource(DS.Tables[0]);
    RD.Subreports[0].DataSourceConnections.Clear();
    RD.Subreports[0].SetDataSource(dataSet.Tables[0]);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = RD;
    CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Please post your full code for your crystal report.

Comment: That's the full code @James Dev

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the SetReportSource method, then SetParameterValue before loading the report.

Comment: Thanks @ hiennm but i already did that. that's what the first line does

Answer (score 1):

From my experience with the Crystal SDK, it will always pop that up at runtime unless you set all of the parameters the report has. Double check the report and make sure you're not missing any.

Comment: I have, and that's the only parameter i have. I'm trying to supply an image path.

Comment: Are you using the report viewer control from crystal? And what Service Pack are you on?

Comment: Version=13.0.2000.0.

Comment: Have you tried getting the latest service pack to test? I don't know if your response is a typo, but the latest version is 13.0.16.1954 http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824